# Как установить графический интерфейс xfce в оффлайн режиме?

Tags: install, xfce, bsd

У меня есть друг который купил компьютер с установленной NetBSD операционной системе (без графического интерфейса) и у него нет доступа к интернету. Можно ли установить графический интерфейс xfce в оффлайн режиме и достаточна ли для установки один Xfce tar архив из официального сайта https://xfce.org/?

Comment: На нэтбсд нет интернета? С трудом верится в это, а точнее вообще не верится. Не бывает такого, чтобы на UNIX были проблемы с сетью.

Comment: @misdeed я имел в виду что у моего друга нет интернета а не в NetBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В: Можно ли установить графический интерфейс xfce в оффлайн режиме и достаточна ли для установки один Xfce tar архив из официального сайта https://xfce.org/?

О: Да, можно. Да, достаточно!

Может у вас еще есть какие-то вопросы?

Comment: А как это сделать? Может есть какие нибудь документации, сайты и другие материалы где сказано как сделать это детально?

Comment: не могли бы вы ответили на мой вопрос! Это для меня очень важно. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @Denny00, примерно как здесь: https://askubuntu.com/questions/695536/how-to-install-xfce-desktop-environment-from-xfce-4-6-1-src-tar-bz2

Comment: @Denny00, если еще будут какие-либо вопросы - обращайтесь, не стесняйтесь. Надеюсь, вы сможете перенести tar.gz с флешки на систему? С этим не будет трудностей?

Comment: @Denny00, https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-mind-blowing-xfce-4-12-desktop-environment-linux-features/

Comment: Спасибо :) Извините за беспокойствие но ещё вопрос мой дорогой друг: А как перенести tar.gz с флешки на систему? Заранее благодарен ! :)

Comment: @Denny00 ```cp```

Comment: спасибо огромное ! :)